# How to catch and ignore UserWarning "no features" with GridSearchCV, when used along with pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-selection, grid-search

```
feat_sel = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1'))
clf = svm.LinearSVC()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('fs',feat_sel), ('clf',clf)])
param = dict(fs__estimator__C=np.logspace(-2, 4, 7),clf__C=np.logspace(-3, 1, 5))
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param, cv=5)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

I am trying to tune hyperparameters of a model (eg: logistic regression), which i then use to select the features. But, sometimes no features will be selected when selection criterion (eg small C) is too strict.

```
UserWarning: No features were selected: either the data is too noisy or the selection test too strict.
```

Is there any way to catch this error and make GridSearchCV to drop that particular value of parameter and move on with the next, without causing the code to interrupt? I would like to have it this way because my X changes dynamically.